Pivot multiple values to columns
This question may have been answeered, but I can't seem to find the right keywords to search.
current df:



index
time
value
type
test




0
0.00
0.112
A
test1


1
0.01
0.113
A
test1


0
0.00
0.112
A
test2


1
0.01
0.113
A
test2



Desired df: (each unique value of test gets its own column)



index
time
test1
test2
type




0
0.00
0.112
0.112
A


1
0.01
0.113
0.112
A


0
0.00
0.112
0.112
B


1
0.01
0.113
0.112
B



I have tried this code:
df_pvt = df.pivot(index = ['index','type'],columns = 'test', values='value')

but, I get a bunch of NaN values and the row count for df_pvt is the same as df, even though it should be 1/5 of the length for 5 unique test values.

I have tried:  df_pvt = df.pivot_table(index = ['time','Type'],columns = 'Test',values='value')    This works better, but now I have separate rows for each 'type'. I want to retain the time and type columns

pandas.wide_to_long to the rescue!
